# Make Merge of leaflet Polygons on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on a case now, in which the user can select 2 or more polygons on the map. I want to merge these polygons each time user clicks on a new one. This is what I did so far ... But seems it doesn't work well because I need to clear the previous layer before calling it again .

```
$("#merge").click(function() {
   console.log('Merge Request !');
   var merged;
   var selected = [];
   geojson.on('click', function(e) {
      selected.push(e.layer.toGeoJSON());
      if (selected.length == 2){
         var pol = turf.union(selected[0], selected[1]);
         var merged = L.geoJson(pol,{'style': function() {
               return {
                  'color': 'white',
               }
            }
         }).addTo(map);
         merged.bringToFront();

         selected = [];
         selected.push(pol);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx "I want to merge these polygons each time user clicks on a new one" the question is how to do it given the code I did because it doesnt work well for me .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407512/287948

Comment: thanks @PeterKrauss for the first principals on this, but has anyone got a leaflet based solution?